# On the iPhone SDK, is there a way I can disable touch interactions on the textview? In a way that allows touches to be recieved by things behind it?

Tags: iphone, sdk

For my iPhone game I wrote the entire thing in OpenGL ES, and now I'm trying to overlay a TextView to display a scoreboard. The problem is now my touch input doesn't work correctly, because the Textview is recieving the touch input rather than my opengl view. Is there a way I can just disable touch interactions on the textview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer, in case anyone else runs in to this:
[textView setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
It does in fact send touches to the things behind it.

Answer (score 0):

UIView should have a property that you can set to enable or disable touch interactions, now will it make it so the text view is no longer in the way and the view underneath it will pick up touch events? I dont know youll have to check :)